# How can I upload and parse my local Excel inside an Angular component, when it loads, without having to upload and submit it by hand?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, parsing, xlsx

I had a solution in vanilla JavaScript, that required me to use a submit button and look through my PC.

But now I need to have the file directly uploaded on component creation and parsed preferably using the old JavaScript code (so that I don't lose a lot of time, again, with this, because I created some specific subarrays and objects based on the parsing result).

Here's my JavaScript code down below, which was initially meant to be used with a simple index.html file but now needs to be adapted for Angular's app-component:

```
let files;
let filename;
let extension; 

function upload() {
    // input responsible for taking file from folder
    // submitted via button, but now I need it when app-component.onload
    files = document.getElementById('file_upload').files;

    if(files.length==0){
      alert("Please choose any file...");
      return;
    }

    filename = files[0].name;
    extension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".")).toUpperCase();

    if (extension == '.XLS' || extension == '.XLSX') {
        excelFileToJSON(files[0]);
    }else{
        alert("Please select a valid excel file.");
    }

}

let reader;
let data;
let workbook;
let result = {};
let roa;
let resultEle;

function excelFileToJSON(file){
    try {
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            data = e.target.result;
            workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                type : 'binary'
            });

            result = {};
            workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
                roa = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
                
                if (roa.length > 0) {
                    result[sheetName] = roa;
                }
            });

            //displaying the json result
            resultEle=document.getElementById("json-result");
            resultEle.value=JSON.stringify(result, null, 4);
            resultEle.style.display='block';
        }
    }catch(e){
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

and the imports for XLSX parser (SheetJS?), jQuery and Axios inside the old index.html:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.17.5/xlsx.min.js"></script>   
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```